# Fluent Validation for if string not null then check is valid email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I am using fluent validation library for my asp.net mvc5 project . my requirement is if user input email then if validate valid email address otherwise its not validate it is valid email address or not

Comment: Although the answer in the linked question is similar to the answer for this question, they are not the same question.  The other question asks "how do I validate NOT null AND valid email", whereas this question asks "how do I validate null OR valid email".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do as follows with `Fluent Validation` method chaining:

```
RuleFor(s => s.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email address is required")
                     .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Your email address is not valid");
```

If your email field is `not required` then validate as follows:

```
RuleFor(s => s.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Your email address is not valid");
```

try this, If your email field is not required then validate Email Address:

> `RuleFor(e => e.Email).EmailAddress().When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email)).WithMessage("Your email address is not valid");`

Comment: My requirement is if user input email text box then it validate otherwise it not checking any validation for this text box

Comment: That means your Email input field is not required, am I right?

Comment: yes please tell me how i validate this scenario
RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().When(x=>x.Email.IsNotNullOrEmpty()).Must(EmailExits);
but this code is not working plz help how can i solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried this:  `RuleFor(s => s.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Your email address is not valid");`

Comment: only validate this text field if user input anything this text box otherwise not

Comment: Yes! Understood Try this : `RuleFor(s => s.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Your email address is not valid");` and make sure that `Email` field in your model does not contain any `Required` attribute.

Comment: Your rule for non-required Email didn't work for me. Had to use 
`RuleFor(e => e.EmailAddress).EmailAddress().When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmailAddress));`
Otherwise it threw a validation error if it was empty.

Comment: Had the same issue.
I can confirm that even if you don't mark the property as required, it still gets validated unless you add what @LaurieDickinson said `.When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmailAddress));`